# jSon parseError - Swift

Tags: swift

I enter the parameter and take data with the MVC project. It pulls the data but prints the result in the responsestring variable in the catch parseerror line. How can I withdraw this data?

**parsing error:** Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
**raw response:** Optional("\"/Uploads/GV8ptzoREovS-119.png\"")

```
 @objc func gorselCEK(){
        var urlComponent = URLComponents(string: ".../MobilService/KategoriGorsel/")!

        urlComponent.queryItems = [
              URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: "7")
          ]

        var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponent.url!)

        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


                          request.httpMethod = "GET"

                         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                              guard let data = data else {
                                 // print("request failed \(error)")
                                  return
                              }


                              do {
   if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? String,
                                    let sifre : String = json {
                                                                   print("sifre", sifre)

                                                                     }

                              } catch let parseError {
                                  print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
                                  let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                                  print("raw response: \(responseString)")
                              }
                          }
                          task.resume()
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the error message:

> JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.

So as the object is not a collection type you have to set the option:

```
if let sifre = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? String {
```

And the URLRequest is redundant. The content type header is not considered in a GET request anyway.

Comment: Why still use JSonSerialization in that case?